# Limit number of form submissions

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, forms-services

Is there anyway to limit the number of times a user can submit a form within sharepoint 2010 using a form created by infopath 2010?
I have a workflow that I am trying to implement this into.
We are creating a device sale site where the user can purchase one device and if they have already purchased a device it will send their submission to a waitlist.
We are using Sharepoint Designer and trying to use standard out of the box solutions instead of code.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list that is just a user column and a second column that is single line of text and defaults to 1.

The workflow could check if that user exists in the column (if value equals value where the first value returns the single line of text, and checks the user column looking for the user who created the form and the second value is 1). Then based on the result you either send an email to the purchase group and add the user to the User List, or email the waitlist.

Let me know if this makes sense.

Note that if the user is not in the User List, it ***should*** return null = 1 which of course is false, but that needs to be tested to make sure.